# Create a function with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, function, phpmyadmin

I have trouble creating a function using [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) like an interface for [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).
So I write:

```
DELIMITER //
Create or Replace Function  affecter (id_patient IN integer , id_maladie IN VARCHAR2 ) 
Return VARCHAR2(30) IS  msg Varchar2(30);
Begin
    Insert into souffrir values (id_patient,id_maladie);
    msg:= 'Insertion effectuée';
    Return msg;
END//
```

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>        MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Function affecter (id_patient 
>      IN   integer , id_maladie IN VARCHAR2 ) Returns V' at line 1

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION calcProfit(cost FLOAT, price FLOAT) RETURNS DECIMAL(9,2)
BEGIN
  DECLARE profit DECIMAL(9,2);
  SET profit = price-cost;
  RETURN profit;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Got it from https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/mysql-stored-functions-and-procedures

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) does not have an 'or replace' part of the create function. You should instead, after defining the delimiter, add a `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS` with the function name.

See *[13.1.12. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)*.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the SQL tab in PMA, just below the big box for entering your SQL, there's a small input field for the delimiter. Remove `DELIMITER //` from your SQL, change the delimiter input  field from ';' to '//' paste your code and submit it.