# SQL query to update all headlines in Wordpress database

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wordpress

I like to replace all my custom headlines in my wordpress blog posts with regulat “h” headlines. For example:

```
[x_custom_headline type=“left“ level=“h2″ looks_like=“h3″]Here is the headline[/x_custom_headline]
```

should replaced to

```
<h2>Here is the headline</h2>
```

and

```
[x_custom_headline type=“left“ level=“h3″ looks_like=“h7″]Here is another headline[/x_custom_headline]
```

should replaced by

```
<h3>Here is another headline</h3>
```

I have more than 1000 posts, so doing this manually would take weeks or month...

T tried something like:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
    SET post_content = REPLACE(
      REPLACE(post_content, '[x_custom_headline type="left" level="h2" looks_like="h3"]', '<h2>'),
      '[/x_custom_headline]','</h2>')
WHERE post_content LIKE '[x_custom_headline type="left" level="h2" looks_like="h3"]%[/x_custom_headline]';
```

**...but the WHERE condition does not work in this query.**

Can anybody maybe help me to find the right SQL query (maybe regex?) to update this directly in the database?

This is a typical post structure:

```
Post Content
[x_custom_headline type="left" level="h2" looks_like="h3"]This is a h2 headline[/x_custom_headline]
Post Content
[gallery ids="92149,92151,92153,92155"]
More Post Content
[x_custom_headline type="left" level="h3" looks_like="h7"]This is a h3 headline[/x_custom_headline]
More Post Content
[x_custom_headline type="left" level="h3" looks_like="h7"]This is a h3 headline[/x_custom_headline]
More Post Content
<img src="image-url" class="skip-lazy"/>
[x_custom_headline type="left" level="h2" looks_like="h3"]This is a h2 headline[/x_custom_headline]
More Post Content
[sc name="reiseberichte-seychellen"]
More Post Content
```

Michael

Comment: How many different levels are there?

Comment: I think 2, maximum 3.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? If you're not sure run the query `select version();`

Comment: on my staging 10.3.32-MariaDB-log-cll-lve, on my live system I have version 8.0.25-15

Answer (score 0):

Here we have created a function which loops using `WHILE`until it no longer finds `="h[1-6]` in the string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION h_tag_while
       (wp_post varchar(1000))
RETURNS varchar(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE poste varchar(1000);
  DECLARE posH int;
  DECLARE posT int;
  DECLARE Hx char(2);
  SET poste = wp_post;
  SET Hx = right(regexp_substr(
      poste,'="h[1-6]'),2);
WHILE LEFT(Hx,1) = 'h' DO
  SET posT =  locate(
  '[/x_custom_headline]',poste);
  SET posH = locate(
   '[x_custom_headline type="left"',
   poste);
   SET poste = concat(
    substring(poste,1,posH-1),
    '<',Hx,'>',
    substring(poste,posH+58,posT-posH-58),
    '</',Hx,'>',
    substring(poste,posT+20));
   SET Hx = right(regexp_substr(
      poste,'=[″"]h[1-6]'),2);
 END WHILE;
RETURN coalesce(poste,wp_post);
END
```

we can see the output with the query

```
select 
  h_tag_while(post_content)
from wp_posts;
```

and when we are satisfied that all is well we can modify the data in the table with

```
update wp_posts
set post_content = h_tag_while(post_content);
```

See the following dbfiddle for testing and development.
There is also the first function which only updates the first occurrence of `="h[1-6]`. The other problem is that it returns `null` if the search does not succeed.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have never worked with CREATE FUNCTION before. Can I run this under the regular SQL tab in phpmyadmin? When I do this I get an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 Or do I have to add this function unser the tab "Routines"?

Comment: Please see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65177bca8fdf7d316b69565c5f075885 to test and let me know. I'll have another look this evening.

Comment: It works perfectly on dbfiddle. But I can´t transfer this to my phpmyadmin :(

Comment: Have a look at. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176583/create-a-function-with-phpmyadmin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481890/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-in-phpmyadmin and see whether you can make it work. Try with a simple function from a tutorial first?

Comment: I really tried it. It was no problem to add a simple function to my phpmyadmin. But when I try to add your code I get SQL Syntax Errors: MySQL meldet: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ CREATE FUNCTION h_tag_while (wp_post varchar(1000)) RETURNS varchar' at line 1

Comment: Personally I find that the $$ seperator causes more problems than it solves. That's why I haven't used it here . Did you try without it? You should be able to create a function in the SQL tab and in the routines tab so try both.

Comment: Yes, I tried both and unfortunately it did not work. I do not know what the problem is. Does it still make sense to discuss this further here in the forum? I really thank you very much for your help. And I really need this solution!!! But I'm afraid about the forum we do not get further. Maybe you can contact me directly omp-blog(at)gmx.com?